# Sending data back and forth from two Raspberry Pi's with socket library

Tags: python, sockets, server, raspberry-pi, client

I've been having trouble sending data between two pi's using socket.send and socket.recv commands in python. I've followed an example on YouTube to help get the code started but whenever I try to send other types of data from the server to the client, the server stops and the client receives an empty value.

**Server:**

```
import socket
import time

host = '192.168.10.100'
port = 9988

def setupServer():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    print("Socket created.")
    try:
        s.bind((host, port))
    except socket.error as msg:
        print(msg)
    print("Socket bind complete.")
    return s

def setupConnection():
    s.listen(1) # Allows one connection at a time.
    conn, address = s.accept()
    print("Connected to: " + address[0] + ":" + str(address[1]))
    return conn

def dataTransfer(conn):
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024) # receive the data
        data = data.decode('utf-8')
        if data == 'kill':
            print("Server is shutting down.")
            s.close()
            break
        elif data == 'test':
            reply = 1
        else:
            reply = 'Unknown Command'
        conn.sendall(reply)
    conn.close()

s = setupServer()

while True:
    try:
        conn = setupConnection()
        dataTransfer(conn)
    except:
        break
```

**Client:**

```
import socket
from time import sleep

host = '192.168.10.100'
port = 9988

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host, port))

while True:
    command = input("Enter command: ")
    if command == 'KILL':
        s.send(str.encode(command))
        break
    s.send(str.encode(command))
    reply = s.recv(1024)
    print(reply)

s.close()
```

When I run the 'kill' command it works normally:

[image: server side]

[image: client side]

But when I try to run 'test', the server script seems to close and the client seems to receive an empty value instead of 1.

[image: server side test]

[image: client side test]

After looking around it looks like I may be running into blocking/non-blocking issues or the socket.send/socket.recv commands aren't transferring the correct types of data. Perhaps I might have some other errors?

Comment: Have you tried replying with the string `"1"` when you receive a `"test"` instead of with an `int`?

Comment: Thanks @BorrajaX I will try this.

Answer (score 1):

When the `data=="test"` condition is hit, you're assigning your `reply` to an integer value. `socket.sendall` takes a `string` argument. Try `"1"`.

As a suggestion, this would be a good opportunity to use pdb to debug if you're not familiar with it. Simply `import pdb` and wherever you want the program to pause (e.g. in the server's if block where `data=="test"`), then simply have a statement `pdb.set_trace()` and it will open an interactive terminal if the message is being received properly.

Comment: Thanks I'll try this. the debug also sounds very helpful.

Comment: After setting reply = 1 to reply = "1" I still get the same exact results. The server closes and the client receives an empty value. I've also tried the pdb debug and it doesn't seem to trace.